# How can I track C++ memory allocations on iOS?

Tags: c++, ios, memory, memory-management, unreal-engine4

We're developing a mobile game using UE4. And we add a bunch of third-party SDKs whose memory is not managed by Game Engine. The SDKs is pre-compiled. Memory Leaks is annoying. Is there any way to get the detail of memory allocations on iOS? Can I hook the malloc function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Instruments for this. The Leaks instrument finds memory leaks and the Allocations instrument shows you all memory that is being allocated (including heap and virtual memory). It’s to broad to explain it all here. Read the documentation and play around with it.